# Properties of quotient group $\frac{\Bbb{Q}}{\Bbb{Z}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group, infinite-groups

Consider the quotient group $\frac{\Bbb{Q}}{\Bbb{Z}}$

So $\frac{\Bbb{Q}}{\Bbb{Z}}$ = $\{\frac{p}{q}: p, q \in \Bbb{Z}, q \neq 0\}$

Now consider $\Bbb{Z}$+$\frac{r}{m}$ where $m$ is a natural number and $1 \leq r \leq m$ and $gcd(r,m)$ = $1$.

I want to show that order of $\Bbb{Z}$+$\frac{r}{m}$ is $m$.

Now ($\Bbb{Z}$+$\frac{r}{m}$)$^m$ = $\Bbb{Z}$

This implies that order of $\Bbb{Z}$+$\frac{r}{m}$ divides $m$.

Let $1 \leq p \leq m$

Then how can we show that ($\Bbb{Z}$+$\frac{r}{m}$)$^p$ $\neq$ $\Bbb{Z}$.

The left hand side of the above expression is  $\Bbb{Z}$+$\frac{pr}{m}$

How to show that $\frac{pr}{m}$ isn't an integer ?

Comment: $p$ divides $m$ so $m=p\cdot q$ but $(r,m)=1$ and so $(r,q)=1$ there are two options, either $q=1$ you win or $q>1$ and so $r/q\not \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Your description of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ in the second line is not quite right; what you describe are the rationals (once you mod out by the usual relation to account for multiple representations), not the quotient. Also, this is an additive group, so you should not have $(\mathbb{Z}+\frac{r}{m})^m$, you should have $m(\mathbb{Z}+\frac{r}{m})$.

Comment: I think you are mixing up additive and multiplicative notation.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$m \cdot (\mathbb Z + r/m) = \mathbb Z + m r/m = \mathbb Z + r = \mathbb Z$$

and $$k \cdot (\mathbb Z + r/m) = \mathbb Z + k r/m$$

this only equals $\mathbb Z$ when $kr/m$ is an integer. We saw that this happens when $k=m$. An in fact it wont happen before that because $r$ is coprime to $m$.

---

Details on the arithmetic:

Let $(r,m)=1$ and $1 \le k < m$, then $kr/m$ is not an integer.

In other words, $m \not | \; kr$.

Since $(r,m)=1$, $m | \; kr$ iff $m | \; k$.

Comment: Why can't m divide k?

Comment: It can be equal to k